# How to run a simple tests on different platforms (at the same time, in parallel) using pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, pytest, paramiko

Let's say I have some test suites which are testing a specific application using some steps like installing it in setup phase, check if it works fine and uninstall it in teardown phase.

To run it locally, it is easy by just using:

```
python3 -m pytest /suites/test_app1.py
```

But, what if I want to run this test on different platforms at the same time and extract the results (allure) for each of them. Let's say my current working machine is Windows and I want to run it in also 3 other different platforms (Ubuntu22, Ubuntu20, RHEL8) at the same time?

I know that I can use `paramiko` feature to run it, but this somehow (based on what I understood, can run only 1 platform at a time using:

```
python3 -m pytest /suites/test_app1.py --ssh-config="/path_to_conif/" -hosts=Ubuntu22 --sudo
```

And then the config file would look like this:

```
Host Ubuntu22
  HostName 192.168.1.1
  User root
  Password root
  Port 22
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile "C:\ubuntu22.pub"
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
  
Host Ubuntu20
  HostName 192.168.1.2
  User root
  Password root
  Port 22
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile "C:\ubuntu20.pub"
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL

Host RHEL8
  HostName 192.168.1.3
  User root
  Password root
  Port 22
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile "C:\rhel8.pub"
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```